# get popular tags with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tags, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  tags: [String]
});
```

now, suppose I want to get all 'popular tags', I would do the following:

1. create a temp array
2. find last n elements
3. loop through them and add all tags to the array
4. remove duplicates
5. return array

It does not seem the most efficient way to do things; is there a better way to achieve the same result, considering also indexing issues with what can become a really big collection.

Comment: This is directly covered in the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could likely be clearer but it seems that what you want to do is accumulate the counts of all of your "tags" across all of the documents in your collection.

So rather than looping results in code, you can use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },

    // Group on tags with a count
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$tags",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Optionally sort the tags by count descending
    { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },

    // Optionally limit to the top "n" results. Using 10 results here
    { "$limit": 10 }
])
```

That will then return the top 10 favored tags by count of how many times they appeared.

There is the model function for [aggregate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) available for Mongoose, so you can look at the similar syntax there.